# Unity Facebook SDK publish actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a problem when posting player score via the unity facebook sdk.
The code for the scores API is calling fine, but the only problem is that the App cannot grant the publish_actions permission when the user login. 
I tried with and without the native facebook app, also login with the init() dialogue or the function below: 
*FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);*

I checked the permission in the App Settings in the tester account and its only showing Basic Information which cannot post. I will greatly appreciate if you can give me advices. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you try requesting just the publish_actions permission?  Also, what platform were you running on?

Comment: Not I cannot. I deploy the game on nexus 7 which is running Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Just use the publish_actions and not the email..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I solved this with using the newer version of the plugin (4.2.4) with the same logic, so I guess its just a issue of the old version.